# Compare dates which are strings and which have no day

Tags: mysql, sql, string, datetime, where-clause

I want to compare dates which are strings and which have no day.
My table looks like this :

```
+-------------+------------------+
| mois(str)   |     nbr(int)     |  
+-------------+------------------+
| 2020-01     | 4132             |  
| 2020-02     | 7851             |  
| 2020-03     | 8351             | 
| 2020-04     | 1564             |  
| 2020-05     | 1452             |  
| 2020-06     | 6421             |  
+-------------+------------------+
```

I want for example to get every lines between '2020-02' and '2020-04' according to the column 'mois'

```
+-------------+------------------+
| mois(str)   |     nbr(int)     |  
+-------------+------------------+
| 2020-02     | 7851             |  
| 2020-03     | 8351             | 
| 2020-04     | 1564             | 
+-------------+------------------+
```

Could you help me ? Thank you !

Comment: *...between '2020-02' and '2020-04'..* Didn't you try `where mois between '2020-02' and '2020-04'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That `YYYY-MM` format makes it possible to direct filtering, so you can just do:

```
where mois >= '2020-02' and mois <= '2020-04'
```

Or using `between`:

```
where mois between '2020-02' and '2020-04'
```

Comment: I was so focused on comparing dates that I forgot about the string comparison, thank you very much haha